# moving from inner navigation controller to outer navigation controller

Tags: ios, nested, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app, I am presenting the UIimagePickerController from a outer navigation controller (c1)[It is presented modally]
.Upon selecting an image from picker I try to edit the image selected from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. I try to present this editing controller by pushing it in UIimagePickerController and presenting it. So now i have a nested navigation controller 
At the outer level I have C1 and inner level navigation controller is the UIimagePickerController.

After editing the photo I want to go back to the rootviewcontroller of my outer navigation controller. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: [self.navigationController popToRootViewController];

Comment: poptoRootViewController can only take me to the root view controller of inner navigation controller, but i want to move to the root view controller of outer navigation controller

Comment: did you try [self.navigationController.navigationController popToRootViewController];

Comment: Nope, but I guess I had to change my design because having nested navigation controllers are discouraged. Thanks for the comments